# Animate on scroll - animation buildups issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text static text element that changes when user scrolls more than 600px and again when it scrolls more than 1400px

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {                    
    $('.p-circle').html('Text 1');
    $('.p-circle-s').html('Text 2');                     
  } 
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1400) { 
    $('.p-circle').html('Text 1 updated');     
    $('.p-circle-s').html('Text 2 updated');
  }
});
```

How can I make a basic animation of fading for them, I tried next variants and they don't work well (it is fading 2 times)

```js
if (scrollTop > 600 && scrollTop <= 1400) { 
    
  $('.p-circle').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('Text 1').fadeIn(500);
  });
  $('.p-circle-s').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('Text 2').fadeIn(500);
  });   
      
} else if (scrollTop > 1400 && scrollTop <= 2100) {

  $('.p-circle').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('Text 1 updated').fadeIn(500);
  });
  $('.p-circle-s').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).text('Text 2 Updated').fadeIn(500);
  }); 

}
```

Comment: PS: you don't need to use *two* `$(window).scroll(function () {` 

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan they do, it's chained at the end there.

Comment: @Travis eagle eyes. Missed that

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good call on the two $(window).scroll functions, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, however your logic in that last bit there isn't testing whether the transition already happened. Something along the lines of:

`if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 1400 && $(".p-circle").text() != 'Text 1')`

I think I got your values wrong, but here's a fiddle to get you on the right track...

https://jsfiddle.net/64mj3k7n/3/

Comment: Sorry, just updated that fiddle link, it was the old one.

Comment: From experience, you don't need to check for the text, just for the scrollTop value. Change the text accordingly.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think they issue they're having is that any time they scroll, it's going to fade out and fade back in whether they scrolled far enough to change the text or not. Maybe I'm missing the problem they're having.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that sounds like wise advice though I don't know where it belongs. https://jsfiddle.net/64mj3k7n/4/ has a .stop() at the beginning at the chain, is that how you mean (to kill any animation that may be in progress)? It's a less satisfying user experience and means that the animation won't start until the scroll ends. Did you mean it belongs somewhere else?

Comment: Travis, I tested and no, I created a demo of OP's code and I think you're right. The scroll event triggers too many times and the `.stop()` is just the wrong approach to the initially wrong one :)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to create a function (or Class) `Waypoints`, to be used like:

```js
Waypoints(window, [0, 100, 600, 1400], (wp) => {
  console.log(wp);   // {index:Int, value:Int}
});
```

which accepts three arguments:

1. an **Element** (or **String** selector) to *scroll-watch*
2. an **Array** of scrollY waypoints values
3. a **callback Function**

The callbacks is triggered **only once a scroll index changes** — in order to prevent buildups on every scroll Event call.

```js
/**
 * Waypoints
 * Trigger callbacks on a scrollY milestone 
 * @url https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520524/383904
 * @param {string|object} el String selector or Element object
 * @param {array} waypoints Array of px from lower to higher
 * @param {function} cb Callback function
 */

function Waypoints(el, waypoints = [0], cb) {
  el = (typeof el === "string") ? document.querySelector(el) : el;
  const wp = [...waypoints].reverse();
  const wpTot = wp.length;
  const getIndex = (n) => {
    const i = wp.findIndex(m => m <= n);
    return wpTot - 1 - (i < 0 ? wpTot : i);
  };
  let index = -1;
  const getTask = () => {
    const i = getIndex(el.scrollY);
    if (index === i) return; // No task to trigger
    index = i; // Update index
    const value = wp[wpTot - 1 - i]; // Get the waypoint name
    cb({ index, value }); // Trigger the callback
  };
  el.addEventListener("scroll", getTask);
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => getTask);
  window.addEventListener("load", () => getTask);
  getTask();
}


/**
 * YOUR APP:
 */

const $circle1 = $('.p-circle');
const $circle2 = $('.p-circle-s');

const circle1txt = ["Text 1 scroll", "Text 1", "Text 1 updated"];
const circle2txt = ["Text 2 scroll", "Text 2", "Text 2 updated"];

Waypoints(window, [0, 600, 1400], (wp) => {
  $circle1.fadeOut(500, () => {
    $circle1.text(circle1txt[wp.index]).fadeIn(500);
  });
  $circle2.fadeOut(500, () => {
    $circle2.text(circle2txt[wp.index]).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```css
body { height: 3000px; } /* Just to force some scrollbars for this demo */
[class^="p-"] { position: fixed; }
.p-circle-s { top: 2rem; }
```

```html
<div class="p-circle"></div>
<div class="p-circle-s"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a cool little function, but I wonder in what way it's better than just adding a test in the if to see if if the text needs to be changed? That's a lot of code and I don't think I can tell the difference between the end results....

Comment: @Travis hardcoding arbitrary text inside a JS logic was never a good idea. And will never be one :) In your example you're left with too many `if` statements and text-checking. Bug prone and it's not DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: I would agree with that, but the complexity of that code seems like overkill for this application. I would tend toward just creating a few constants for the text, but perhaps I over-value simplicity. It is a cool function.

Comment: Travis, it's exactly not an overkill. The function is small as is and will never grow (unless you add more features like defining waypoints in String units like `"20%"` or fractions like `"@0.5"`) - but that's another story. Now, consider you add 100 more waypoints, now tell me which code will become an overkill to maintain and even code all the different statements?

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. If you have more than two or three breakpoints, I would agree it makes more sense to use a function, and this one works splendidly.